# Деепричастный оборот с двумя деепричастиями

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

Здравствуйте!

Есть предложение:

> Раздув огонь и накидав самых сухих и тонких веток в приготовленную
>   воронку, Антон стал собирать сырые коряги.

Подскажите, нужно ли ставить запятую после слова "огонь"? И почему так, а не иначе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Раздув огонь и накидав самых сухих и тонких веток в приготовленную воронку***, Антон стал собирать сырые коряги.
>
> **...нужно ли ставить запятую после слова "огонь"?**

Не нужно. "Раздув огонь" и "накидав самых сухих и тонких веток..." —  однородные обстоятельства, соединённые союзом "и".

См. [**ПАС:**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121)

> **§ 68.** <…> При сочетании деепричастных оборотов знаки препинания **между ними** расставляются так же, как и при однородных членах
>   предложения: *Он пошел, **пошатываясь и все поддерживая голову
>   ладонью левой руки**, а правой тихо дергая свой бурый ус* (М. Г.).

Comment: Благодарю, а я думал, что это один большой деепричастный оборот с двумя разнородными деепричастиями.